# Can't change render type from single band color data in QGIS 3.16 on DSM LiDAR layer

Tags: qgis, dem, lidar

I can't change the render type from single band color data in QGIS 3.16 on a DSM LiDAR layer.

When I click on the drop down arrow by render type there are no other options. I would like to add multiple colors to the DSM layer.

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  At 3.18.2, I get the usual rendering drop-downs (normal, lighten, screen...) with a single-band, 32-bit, floating-point tif DTM when the rendering is set to singleband pseudocolor.  Makes me wonder if your problem has something to do with your data.  Can you edit your post to fully describe your raster?